# fetch model from json - backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, models

Good morning,
I have a simple json file and I need to fetch my data (I already read thousand of other question about it but not find a good solution for my app).
I have a view, a model a json file. I can fetch my data but I can't display them. 
Here my code:

calendarDetails.json

```
{
"calendarTitle": "WebCal",
"calendarDescription": "Hello, I'm your new calendar"
 }
```

HeaderModel.js

```
    var HeaderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    isEdit: false,
    url: '/assets/calendarDetail.json'
});

headerModel = new HeaderModel();
headerModel.fetch();
```

HeaderView.js

```
var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: HandlebarsTemplates["header"],
    model: headerModel,

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

app.js

```
$(function() {
    var CalendarApp = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#wrap'),

        initialize: function(){
            this.headerModel = new HeaderModel();
            this.headerView = new HeaderView({
                model: this.headerModel,
                el: $('header')
            }),

            this.monthView = new MonthView({
                el: $("#calendarView")
            })
        }
    });

    var calendar = new CalendarApp;

});
```

I'm working with RubyonRails and Handelbars

Any help is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch your model :

```
$(function() {
    var CalendarApp = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#wrap'),

        initialize: function(){
            this.headerModel = new HeaderModel();
            this.headerView = new HeaderView({
                model: this.headerModel,
                el: $('header')
            }); // semicolon here

            this.headerModel.fetch(); // Here

            this.monthView = new MonthView({
                el: $("#calendarView")
            }); // semicolon here
        }
    });

    var calendar = new CalendarApp;

});
```

---

Your problem is that in your `HeaderModel.js` you are instantiating your model and fetching it, so your model will be populated with your json file and that's it.

In your `HeaderView.js` your are affecting your model to the view class, nothing more, the view `initialize` and `render` functions are not yet called.

In your `app.js` when you instantiate your view

```
this.headerView = new HeaderView({
    model: this.headerModel,
    el: $('header')
})
```

your are overriding the previously set model with a new one `this.headerModel` so when the `initialize` and `render` are executed your new model `this.headerModel` is empty.

Comment: Great! it works! So i always need to fetch the models two time? In the model instance and in the app.js?

Comment: No, it's not that. I'll explain more in the answer.